# Bash script result

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Can someone explain me what does the following script?

```
#!/bin/bash
for F in *.txt; do
  K=`grep abc $F`
  echo $K
  if ["$K" != ""]; then
        echo $F
  fi
done
```

I tested it and when it finds a txt file that contains the "abc" string, on prompt appears

```
`"./a.sh: line 5: [abc: command not found"`
```

error, otherwise appears the name of txt file that doesn't contain the "abc" string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is supposed to iterate over all ".txt" files in the current directory, grep them for `abc`, echo the result, and if the string was found, print the file name. However, it has a syntax error (you need spaces around `[` and `]`), breaks on file names with whitespace and is also more complex than needed. A better version is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for F in *.txt; do
  grep abc "$F" && echo "$F"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `[abc: command not found` because you don't have space after `[` and before `]` in your `if` condition.

You don't even need a `for` loop, you can use `grep -l`:

```
grep -l 'abc' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave a space *after* `[` and a space *before* `]` to resolve the errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
for F in *.txt; do
  K=`grep abc $F`
  echo $K
  if [ "$K" != "" ]; then
        echo $F
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script goes through all the `.txt` files in the current directory to search for a pattern and displays the file name where it is matched. Refer to this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/grep.htm

Your code has a syntax error here

```
if ["$K" != ""]
```

You need to put a space after `[` and before `]` hence use this

```
if [ "$K" != "" ]
```